# Designing an interface for methods with different parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, parameters

This is more of a design question than a graphics question, but here's a bit of background: I'm writing a program using OpenGL (in Java, with JOGL) that can load a mesh from a .obj file and render it. No problems so far, but I need to be able to apply a series of filters or transformations to the mesh, e.g.

- Tessellating the faces
- Adding random noise to the vertices
- Applying a smoothing algorithm to the noisy mesh
- Colouring the mesh (which may or may not be based on both the smoothed mesh and the original clean mesh)

Several of these filters would be applied in order. I also want to provide some kind of consistent interface for other people to write their own (possibly general) filters. How would I go about this?

The main problem is that the filters may require different sets of parameters, e.g. one smoothing algorithm may require two parameters to be chosen by the user (at runtime, using the GUI), whereas another might require none. Similarly some colouring algorithms may require only the smoothed mesh and an RGB colour, another might require both the smoothed mesh and the clean mesh (which it generates the colours from). So the call might look like:

```
mesh = smoothingFilter1.filter(mesh, booleanParam);
```

but it might be completely different:

```
mesh = smoothingFilter2.filter(mesh, intParam1, intParam2, floatParam);
```

Obviously my code needs to be capable of invoking a general filtering method. Would it be a good idea to define an abstract class or interface for a `Filter` with an unimplemented method for registering itself (and its required parameters) with some kind of controlling class? Seems pretty complicated but I can't think of any other way to get the program to work with a filter method that has an arbitrary signature. I'm not even sure this idea would work...

Is there a design pattern for handling this type of situation?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, just got round to trying this stuff out and found all 3 answers useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you don't need the parameters at all. `Mesh filter(Mesh mesh);` would suffice. 
Move the other parameters to the constructor of the different concrete implementations of the filters.

Looks something like this:

```
Filter smoothingFilter1 = new FirstFilter(booleanParam);    
mesh = smoothingFilter1.filter(mesh);

Filter smoothingFilter2 = new SecondFilter( intParam1, intParam2, floatParam);    
mesh = smoothingFilter2.filter(mesh);
```

For instantiating you can use something along the lines of:

```
public interface AbstractFilterFactory {
  Params getRequiredParams();
  Filter createFilter(Params params);
}

public interface Params {
 // some interface that describes specific parameters that are required
 // probably a collection of Parameter classes which has name, type and value information. 
}

public class FirstFilterFactory implements AbstractFilterFactory {
  // return a concrete params object use that to instantiate a concrete filter.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes it a bit easier, but the parameters may vary at runtime and I'd prefer if the code that creates the filters (i.e. calls those constructors with the appropriate parameters) were encapsulated in my framework rather than in the user's code. Also my code needs to know what controls (e.g. sliders etc) and parameter names to put on the GUI so it needs to know in advance what parameters it needs as inputs.

Comment: @HappyPixel added some means of encapsulating constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (which i'm not terribly keen on) is to bundle the parameters up in an object, and use polymorphism to pass different parameters for different objects.

First, a quick and dirty version, using a map:

```
interface Filter {
    Mesh filter(Mesh input, Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

Polymorphic object:

```
abstract class Parameters {
}

interface Filter {
    Mesh filter(Mesh input, Parameters params);
}

class FirstFilterParameters extends Parameters {
    private boolean booleanParam;
    // constructor, getter, possibly setter
}

class FirstFilter implements Filter {
    Mesh filter(Mesh input, Parameters params) {
        FirstFilterParameters ffParams = (FirstFilterParameters)params;
        boolean booleanParam = ffParams.getBooleanParam();
        // etc
    }
}
```

Polymorphic object with type safety through generics:

```
abstract class Parameters {
}

interface Filter<P extends Parameters> {
    Mesh filter(Mesh input, P params);
}

class FirstFilterParameters extends Parameters {
    private boolean booleanParam;
    // constructor, getter, possibly setter
}

class FirstFilter implements Filter<FirstFilterParameters> {
    Mesh filter(Mesh input, FirstFilterParameters params) {
        boolean booleanParam = params.getBooleanParam();
        // etc
    }
}
```

The version with generics makes polymorphic handling of filters harder, though. What do you do if you want to have a list of filters, and a list of parameters, and apply each filter with the corresponding parameters? There's no way to do that safely. You'd have to do some manoeuvre like packing each pair into an object with its own type parameter like `FilterWithParams<P extends Parameters>`, and having a `List<FilterWithParams<?>>`. At which point you've basically reinvented M. Platvoet's solution!

Comment: nice answer. The generics solution seems to me more well suited for the problem than the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Another similar solution, without generics, is to declare an abstract parameter class:

```
abstract class FilterParameters { }
```

Your interface then looks like:

```
interface Filter {
  Mesh filter(Mesh input, FilterParameters params);
}
```

For each new set of parameters needed you declare a new subclass of FilterParameters which can carry all the required parameters.

```
// Foo parameter only.
class FooFilterParameters extends FilterParameters { 
  public Foo getFoo() { }
  // Other stuff.
}

// Foo, Bar and int parameters.
class BarFilterParameters extends FilterParameters { 
  public Foo getFoo() { }
  public Bar getBar() { }
  public int getMagnification() { }
  // Other stuff.
}
```

Each filter method will need to check the type of its parameter:

```
// Foo filter
public Mesh filter(Mesh inMesh, FilterParameters fp) {
  if (!(fp instanceof FooFilterParameters)) {
    throw new IllegalParameterException("Not FooFilterParameters.");
  }
  // Foo filter code here.
}
```

rossum